# in app billing Proguard Duplicate zip entry

Tags: android, proguard, in-app-billing

I have faced a problem, for which I cannot find any solution on a internet. I implemented this library into my project: https://github.com/anjlab/android-inapp-billing-v3

after I implemented it, when I try to generate apk this error appears:

> Warning:Exception while processing task java.io.IOException: Can't write [C:\Users\tomas\StudioProjects\TalisProject\app\build\intermediates\transforms\proguard\release\jars\3\1f\main.jar] (Can't read [C:\Users\tomas\StudioProjects\TalisProject\app\build\intermediates\classes\release(;;;;;;**.class)] (Duplicate zip entry [com/android/vending/billing/IInAppBillingService$Stub$Proxy.class]))

After I added this code into my proguard:

```
-keep class com.android.vending.billing.**
-outjars  build\intermediates\transforms\proguard\release\jars\3\1f\main.jar
-outjars out.jar(**.class)
-dontwarn com.android.vending.billing.**
```

> Warning:Exception while processing task java.io.IOException: The output jar [C:\Users\tomas\StudioProjects\TalisProject\app\build\intermediates\transforms\proguard\release\jars\3\1f\main.jar] must have a filter, or all subsequent output jars will be empty.

Does anyone know how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 6):

Check if you have aidl file in your project. And if you have it just remove.

Comment: yes, it works after removing the previous aidl file. Thanks.

Comment: Why does this work when the first thing that google tells us to do is to add the aidl file.
https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_integrate.html

Comment: Because it's was already added in library (https://github.com/anjlab/android-inapp-billing-v3) and you just duplicate it.

Comment: Worked for me as well. Thanks!